# How do I protect my templates/views with PHP user auth?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authentication, httpd.conf

I have a webapp where I've kept most of my PHP code separate in controllers. These controllers have user authentication at the beginning of the file. If the user is authenticated the rest of the code runs and depending on the action, an HTML template/view is included. These template files have the naming scheme file.html.php.

So my question, I have user auth on the controller, but what is stopping someone from just hitting my templates in the URL? Mind you, these templates are 100% useless because the data isn't being pulled from the database as all my PHP/database code is in the controller.

One way to stop this would be to add the authentication check to my template files but then I'm checking auth multiple times on a regular page load.

Another way is i've thought about editing my httpd.conf in apache to deny access to these files with a reg expression, just like .htaccess files are blocked with the following.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Before I do this, what do other people do in this situation?

Comment: how about putting them in a directory below the web root

Comment: hmm, I never thought about that. I'll have to change some code but that seems like good workaround.

Comment: its quite common practice to have anything that does not require direct access outside the web root.